# Deploying android apps for my business

Tags: android, google-apps

I would like to deploy android apps to my employees. We have roughly 900 employees.

I was looking [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en), and it indicates that I have to setup a private channel by enabling Google apps for my domain. I've also read that it costs $50/employees to have my entire company on google apps.

Are there any other ways to deploy android apps strictly to my employee base? Am I really going to have to pay $50 per head?

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to pay that.

- Get a developer licenses from developer.android.com ($25)
- Then create a google group for your Employees and invite them all using their gmail (or other google, see screen shot below) accounts they have installed on their devices.

[image: It allows, I prefer to use my current email address]

Step 1 complete, they are all inside the google group you have specified.

in the developer console:

Upload your apk as an alpha or beta apk (see screen shot below), set up the app as normal with all required fields, but when specifying the testing group you can reference this google group you have just created, which will give you a url that can only be accessed by those google accounts in the group.

[image: Alpha / Beta screenshot]

Send this link out to all the employees that you previously invited to that google group and get them to accept the link for alpha/beta testing.

Once, accepted the employees will be able to download the apk from the Android device with that google account. (The app can then be found in the PlayStore app under Apps & Games -> My apps & Games - > All)

Now anytime you upload a new Alpha/beta apk all users of this group will see the app update or if auto update apps is enable for them, it will happen automatically.

for more details on beta setup: [Alpha/beta help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Good Luck and happy coding!

Comment: I guess it is fair to assume that the people in my company that use Android phones will have an g-mail account. It's pretty hard to exist on Android without one. This seems like a good way to go about it. Thank you for this. I haven't been able to find a similar low-cost solution. This may be the winner.

Comment: @user1571934 more then likely they will, but my mistake above. It does not HAVE to be gmail as long as it is a google account. As you know you can use your own email address when creating a google account.

Answer (score 0):

you can always just install the apk file.

but in that case all your users/employers would have to enable other sources in the settings and get the file on the device somehow and start it(which might require an extra app).

How about just making it a public app and restrict the access to the app somehow (e.g. with a company login)

Comment: I certain that would be messy for app updates. Are there no other services out there for maintaining/deploying android apps for my business?